# How to pass needed parameters to script in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-ise

See Title.

I specified needed parameters in the head of a script:

```
param ($G_ARCHIVE = $(throw "Need file to upload!"),
       $G_LOGFILE = $(throw "Need logfile!"))
```

When I want to debug the script with Powershell ISE: how can I fill these parameters?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use the command pane. Open the script file in the ISE editor, set the breakpoints (F9). Then in the command pane type a command invoking this script with required parameters. I do not think there is another (built-in) way of doing this in ISE.

Comment: This approach did not work for me since my filepath had spaces in it, the solution was to use the "ampersand-function" in the following way: PS C:\Windows> &("c:\my folder\script.ps1") -myArg 123 -anotherArg abc

Comment: You can actually use the relative path: .\script.ps1

Answer (score 36):

1. Open the script (myscript.ps1) in Windows Powershell ISE
2. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> at the variable you want to inspect (debug). For instance 2nd line in the sample below where the $outputText variable is being assigned
3. In the shell window provide the relative path of the script along with the param value. For instance: .\myscript.ps1 "my value"
4. Hit enter (you don't need to hit <kbd>F5</kbd>)
5. You'll be able to see the debugging breakpoints in highlighted with yellow color. Place your cursor to the desired variable to inspect the current value.

[image: A sample showing PowerShell debugging with ISE and command parameter]

Comment: how is this answer different from the accepted one?

Comment: Thought explaining more details with illustration will be helpful for others. For instance providing the relative (or absolute) location is required, which was not provided in the first place.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer because it actually explains what to do and shows the two panes.  I could use this answer, the other one I didn't understand it well enough to know what to do.

Answer (score 19):

There is another way. You can use the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` automatic variable, which exists (since v3) to provide new default arguments to cmdlets and *advanced* functions (doesn't work with normal functions). However, it does work for scripts, even when debugging in ISE. You have to declare `[CmdletBinding()]` or `[Parameter()]` like you would for an advanced function.

So for your example,

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ($G_ARCHIVE = $(throw "Need file to upload!"),
$G_LOGFILE = $(throw "Need logfile!"))
```

you would execute something like this on the ISE Prompt:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.add("ExampleScript.ps1:G_ARCHIVE","File-to-upload.txt")
$PSDefaultParameterValues.add("ExampleScript.ps1:G_LOGFILE","Example.log")
```

You could also set the parameter value to a script block which will auto-execute at run-time:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues["ExampleScript.ps1:G_LOGFILE"]={
  "Example-{0:yyMMddHHmm}.log" -f [datetime]::Now
}
```

The variable is a hashtable and all the standard syntax applies, except the *key* must have the name of the script (or advanced function or cmdlet) followed by a colon then the parameter name. You can set defaults for multiple scripts or commands, and multiple parameters for each (each parameter is a new table entry).

By doing it this way, you can just hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run your script like normal. The parameters will be taken from the variable, so you don't have to type anything in.

Other use cases for `$PSDefaultParameterValues` might be customizations, like have the Get-History get only the last 10 entries, unless you specify the `-Count` parameter in the command. Because entries only persist for the current session, you would want to add customizations to your [profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847857.aspx). You can read more by typing `Get-Help about_Parameters_Default_Values` at the prompt or view the same information on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx).

Comment: Another script block example. You could have your script automatically use the newest zip file. `$PsDefaultParameterValues=["ExampleScript.ps1:G_ARCHIVE"]={(ls *.zip | sort lastwritetime | select -last 1).fullname}` This kind of thing is super useful when you are constantly creating new versions of some external data set to test and debug your script with.

Comment: $PSDefaultParameterValues.Item("KEY") = "VALUE" is another alternative

Comment: It only works in scripts when parameters are declared with a  `[Parameter()]` decorator, which is not the case in 
@eckes example.

Comment: You're right. I mentioned it needed to be an advanced function, but not that you had to do the same with a script.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to set needed Parameters in ISE:

Before pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> in ISE, set the Parameter you need. I usually comment the Parameter I need, example:
    # $G_ARCHIVE = "C:\Temp\TestFile_001.txt"

I select everything after "#" and press <kbd>F8</kbd>. Next time I debug the script with <kbd>F5</kbd>, the Parameter is set to the value I am testing with, no need to pass the Parameters through the command line.

Answer (score 1):

At least in `Powershell 5.1 ISE` when you press `F5` to run a parameterized script, you will be asked to enter values for the parameters one by one.

When using the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` to populate the variables, you can reference the loaded script through the `$psISE` variable like

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.add("$($psISE.CurrentFile.DisplayName):G_ARCHIVE","test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today.  After messing around I discovered that the lower panel was running in Debug  E.g. Prompt '**[Dbg]: PS**'
I stopped the debugging and re-issued my script with paramaeters.
Example: ./myScript.ps1 -ForceBuild $true

My results were that the script started and the breakpoints fired and allowed me to debug as expected.