# Parameters into Powershell_ISE from Command Line

Tags: powershell, command-line, parameter-passing, powershell-ise

I've developed a script in Powershell_ISE to backup a SQL Server database on one server, move the file to another server and restore to the target server with a different database name.  Works fine.

It uses 6 mandatory parameters.  Within Powershell_ISE I can run

```
    C:\PowershellScripts\Servers\CRMBackup.ps1 -SrcSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss -SrcDb UAT_2016_MSCRM
     -SrcBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\ -TrgSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss -TrgDb preprod_mscrm66 -TrgBak 
     \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\
```

and it works fine.

I can't get it to run from the Command Line though.  How do I achieve this?

If I run

```
    powershell_ise.exe "C:\PowershellScripts\Servers\CRMBackup.ps1" -SrcSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss 
    -SrcDb UAT_2016_MSCRM -SrcBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\ -TrgSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss -TrgDb 
    preprod_mscrm66 -TrgBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\
```

from a Command prompt I get an error:

[image: Powershell_ISE parameter error]

If I call Powershell instead of Powershell_ISE, all is fine:

```
    powershell.exe "C:\PowershellScripts\Servers\CRMBackup.ps1" -SrcSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss 
    -SrcDb UAT_2016_MSCRM -SrcBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\ -TrgSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss -TrgDb 
    preprod_mscrm66 -TrgBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\
```

completes successfully:

[image: Successful run from Powershell]

Can anyone advise how to pass command line parameters into Powershell_ISE?

Thanks

Comment: put everything in double quotes? I mean powershell_ise.exe doesn't accept such params:  powershell_ise.exe -h

Comment: Is there a specific reason for wanting to launch ISE to execute your script? Isn't the Powershell command line sufficient?

Comment: Agree - why do you need to run with `powershell_ise.exe`? Just run with `powershell.exe` instead.

Comment: OK, thanks for the unanimous verdict. @Poorkenny - the progress bar when backing up and restoring databases is so much prettier in Powershell_ISE than Powershell!

Comment: You're absolutely right :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot use parameters into Powershell_ISE from Command Line.**

Some background:

You use **PowerShell ISE to develop** your scripts (or notepad or whatever) and you use **powershell.exe to execute** them when finished. You can execute scripts in different ways:

- From a **DOS command**, calling powershell.exe as you indicate in your question.
- From a **PowerShell command**, calling C:\PowershellScripts\Servers\CRMBackup.ps1
- From **Windows Task Scheduler** (or similar tool...)
- From a **CI tool** (Jenkins, TeamCity...)

Of course you can execute scripts from PowerShell ISE while developing them that can be done by clicking Start (or pressing F5) and you can pass parameters as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690235/90608). But you **cannot execute an script passing parameters to powershell_ise.exe**.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some scripts that run fine via ISE, but not via powershell.exe.

Comment: Not totally correct: you can create a .ps1  and use powershell_ise.exe with the -file parameter.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this? (powershell.exe instead of powershell_ise.exe)

```
powershell.exe "C:\PowershellScripts\Servers\CRMBackup.ps1" -SrcSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss -SrcDb UAT_2016_MSCRM -SrcBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\ -TrgSrv uk-sb-sql12\wss -TrgDb preprod_mscrm66 -TrgBak \\uk-sb-sql12\backup\
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you cannot start ISE from command line with your parameters. The list of possible parameters that could only customize your session is here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847883